# Fix - default is not a constructor jest error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have the following code to mock a javascript object.

```
const mockShowOverlay = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./soundPlayer.js', () => {
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
            showOverlay: mockShowOverlay,
            setElement: () => {},
            authContext: {},
            color: "",
            hideOverlay: () => {},
            setOptions: () => {}
        };
    });
});
```

I have the following in jest

```
   expect(mockShowOverlay).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

I'm getting the following error

```
*.default is not a constructor
```

Comment: Where is `mockShowOverlay` coming from?

Comment: see above. I'm just saying I can't run tests becsause my mock is incorrect.

Comment: Let's see your full test code please :)

Comment: I have the same problem : the mock itself seems to work; but when it is used as constructor (with the `new` keyword), it fails.